# How to remove strong typing in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have to convert something read from the database into an object. I might have something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    int a;
    DateTime b;
    float c;

    public Foo(int a, DateTime b, float c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    internal Foo(DataRow dr) {
        this.a = (int) dr["a"];
        this.b = (DateTime) dr["b"];
        this.c = (float) dr["c"];
    }

}
```

is there something you can do, perhaps with the `dynamic` keyword, that can remove type checks and cast automatically? Ideally it would only apply to the `internal` constructor.

Comment: sounds like you want to reinvent the ORM.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes, it would be nice to just use an ORM framework but the system I'm working on isn't using one, so this is what I have to work with.

Comment: So you want to cast DataRow to Foo? I haven't worked without an ORM in ages but is that internal constructor working?

Comment: In addition to @zzzzBov s reaction, you could check out: [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) or [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/)

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Just to skip the casting, you can use simple objects.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
public class Foo {
    dynamic a;
    dynamic b;
    dynamic c;

    public Foo(int a, DateTime b, float c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    internal Foo(DataRow dr) {
        this.a = dr["a"];
        this.b = dr["b"];
        this.c = dr["c"];
    }
}
```

Sure, you can do that if you really hate casting that much, and then the compiler stops being your best friend to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

If getting rid of ugly casts is your main concern, an alternative would be using the [DataRowExtensions.Field<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) method extension.

> Provides strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the specified row.

Usage example:

```
public class Foo {
    int a;
    DateTime b;
    float c;

    public Foo(int a, DateTime b, float c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    internal Foo(DataRow dr) {
        this.a = dr.Field<int>("a");
        this.b = dr.Field<DateTime>("b");
        this.c = dr.Field<float>("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it give any added benefit apart from providing little different syntax than op's ?

Comment: @Arghya: Not really. It just gets rid of ugly casts, which I assume is what bothers OP.  But it essentially does the same, and you're just as vulnerable to `InvalidCastException`s.

Comment: the first one works but is probably very expensive (size and speed), you no longer have (cheap) POCOs you have dynamic magic widegty things

Comment: @pm100: For that reason, and multiple others, I am not advocating that option at all.

Comment: @sstan my comment was intended for the OP

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a dynamic wrapper around the `DataRow` (warning: untested code)

```
public class DynamicDataRow : DynamicObject
{
    private DataRow _dataRow;

    public DynamicDataRow(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        if (dataRow == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataRow");
        this._dataRow = dataRow;
    }

    public DataRow DataRow
    {
        get { return _dataRow; }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (_dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(binder.Name))
        {
            result = _dataRow[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (_dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(binder.Name))
        {
            _dataRow[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then modify your internal constructor as follows:

```
internal Foo(DynamicDataRow ddr) {
    dynamic dr = ddr;
    this.a = dr.a;
    this.b = dr.b;
    this.c = dr.c;
}
```

And call it with

```
var foo = new Foo(new DynamicDataRow(someDataRowObject));
```

Unlike sstan's answer, you will lose all the benefits of compile time type checking. Upfront that sounds like a pretty bad thing, but in actuality it's not quite that bad because even with the `DataRowExtensions.Field<T>` extension method, the type check still happens at run-time because there is no way for the compiler to check that the datatype of the column in the database matches the field that you're trying to stuff that information into. So either way there is going to be run-time type checking.

Comment: Probably `dynamic dr = new DynamicDataRow(row);` so that the caller can go on passing in a `DataRow` as always.

Comment: Yeah, if it's existing/legacy code I would keep the public API the same, but if it's being newly designed I would set the API to take in the type that's actually being used.

Comment: But `DynamicDataRow` is just a conversion helper, an implementation detail.  No reason to expose that as part of the interface.